# Congratulations! Blender is graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Blender has already met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), and today joins in the new design-independent graduation process! Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

You've already had an election to have celebrated this previously, but now you will receive the remaining benefits detailed in this process, which include:

- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Awesome news! Congrats everybody!

Comment: Yay! Congrats everyone! I assume our chance to try and get [custom](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/783/599) [stuff](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/790/599) comes when the design is implemented?

Comment: @gandalf3 We need more then that, http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/610/things-to-address-with-stack-exchange-upon-graduation

Comment: Can't tag the OP, but if anyone can answer this: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/904/does-the-community-have-any-say-over-the-design

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Our chat still says "beta". I think the developers should be notified of this, since this design-less graduation is a new thing.