# Does the community have any say over the design?

Tags: support, graduation, design

Re: [Congratulations! Blender is graduating!](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/congratulations-blender-is-graduating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender site design ideas - input welcome!](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/782/blender-site-design-ideas-input-welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a [discussion post gathering community feedback for the general direction of the design](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/782/blender-site-design-ideas-input-welcome). When the design has been drafted, it will be pitched to the community for review.

Here is an [example pitch for the Movies & TV community](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/updated-january-9-design-for-movies-se).

Comment: Is there a projected timescale for when the draft will be pitched?

Comment: @PGmath [6-8](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/262509) weeks :P