# Improve your old answers party!

Tags: discussion, editing

I recently got an up vote on a [rather old answer of mine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28397/align-uv-map-island-with-axis-or-other-island/28401#28401). I took a moment to read it since I'd forgotten what it said, and promptly discovered it made nearly no sense (the animated gifs made it usable, but it wasn't great). Naturally I promptly [repaired it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/28401/9), but this made my realize how unpolished and poor some of my old answers were.

I thought now, as many users are [getting onto their first year](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) and [our site is graduating](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/congratulations-blender-is-graduating), it would be a good time to look back and clean up some old content and see just how much we have learnt.

**Lets go back and clean up, clarify and correct old answers that we wrote**. Of course you should correct any answer that isn't up to scratch, but lets specifically go out of our way to fix our own content.

**Please post your changes here, one answer per person (use edits)**, so we can see how much is being done, and help motivate ourselves, since seeing other people's contributions is very inspiring, as well as getting some recognition.

Comment: Great idea! I'm sure I have loads of crap answers lying around..

Comment: Nice. We should probably extend the scope of this to include answers that were left in comments instead of as answers.

Comment: @Mentalist Sure, post those results too... I'm still eagerly awaiting some answers :D

Comment: Good idea!  I'll start right away.  I am sure I have some pretty bad stuff left over from when I first started.

Comment: **Update answers that reflect features in newer versions of blender**. Some answers deal with workarounds for features missing or bugged on old blender versions. If you know some new feature that can be used or a workflow that has changed please note it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've done so far:

- [Is there a way to capture the viewport in Blender the same way as it is on 3DS Max?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15211/5705)
- [Weight paint front and back faces at the same time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15774/5705)
- [Repeat a generated texture in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15785/5705)
- [Materials and Exporting to different formats](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15956/5705)
- [Unselectable edge? Help!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16135/5705)

Answer (score 4):

wiki to manual links, is a HUGE job (I have about [90 answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/381984) to change), and nearly every wiki link needs to be manually changed. :(

Also moving my last pastall hosted files.

Another annoyance. All cgcookie links are bad. (switch to youtube if available.)

[Why does the material show 'unexpected' transparency effects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/20880/2217)

[Remove vertex while using knife tool?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/22874/2217)

[My parent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217)

[Which object should be selected when selected to active is check for texture baking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217)

[Make Camera System Look at Empty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28625/2217)

[Object Info Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27932/2217)

[Problem: material has stretched on side of shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27881/2217)

Comment: I started on writing a python script to identify which wiki urls should go to which manual urls (with the idea of generating a list of redirects for the blender wiki servers), but not being a super skilled python expert I have yet to get it to work completely. Perhaps someone with more python experience might like to help?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've updated so far:

- [Iridescence In Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/iridescence-in-cycles/1728#1728)
- [Zoom in and out without a mouse wheel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/zoom-in-and-out-without-a-mouse-wheel/1512#1512)
- [Resource for Blender addons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/resource-for-blender-addons/1343#1343)
- [How do I take a flat model and wrap around an axis like a wheel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-take-a-flat-model-and-wrap-around-an-axis-like-a-wheel/126#126)
- [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing/122#122)

Answer (score 3):

I finally started to get to work on updating some of mine.

The big one is this
[How to distribute objects in a circular pattern on a surface (Radial Array, Polar Array)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31961/how-to-distribute-objects-in-a-circular-pattern-on-a-surface-radial-array-pola/31965#31965)

I updated a few others, but they weren't really significant changes. Removing a dead CGC link, and some small clarifications. In all, I've probably edited around 5-6 so far.